# Jenkins pipeline: one badge per stage?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is it possible, using Jenkins pipeline, to get on badge / shield per stage ? I found a plugin allowing for badge for a complete build but nothing for each stage.

Do you have any idea if it's possible ?

Cheers.